# Making a natural gravy?

Tags: roast, gravy

We generally do a roast on the weekend and we end up with a load of really nice juices in the roasting tray.

What is the best method of turning this into a nice natural gravy?

Comment: Good question! I made gravy yesterday and thought, I'd love to hear what other's think about this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My technique:

- 1 tbsp Fat (from pan, or use butter)
- 1 tbsp Flour
- Pan Juice
- Stock (total liquid about 2 cups - omit if you have enough pan juice)

Step 1: Make Roux

1. Melt fat in medium high saute pan
2. Whisk in flour, getting out all the lumps.  (This is called a roux)
3. Continue to heat until smooth, and the roux is just starting to darken.
4. Remove pan from heat.

Step 2: Prepare Liquids

1. Remove solids from roasting pan. (let meat stand... etc.)
2. Whisk, scrape, deglaze the roasting pan.  If it's brown, you want it, and want it dissolved
3. Strain juices. skim off excess fat.

Step 3: Assemble

1. Return roux to heat, and keep whisking.
2. While whisking, slowly pour in the pan juices.
3. Once blended, reduce heat and let it thicken.  Salt to taste.

Comment: This looks amazing. A vegetarian gravy I usually make has Celery salt in it. Try it out if you've got a chance

Comment: The problem with vegetarian gravy is getting the richness of flavour.  I usually cheat and use a cube of Mushroom stock.
But yes, Celery salt is something I keep hidden away for secret use.  Another good hack is granulated onion powder.

Answer (score 5):

I make sure that there are plenty of onions under the meat when roasting, but be careful not to let them burn. If you are not that keen on onion gravy just leave them out.

Once the meat is done, pour off most of the oil from the cooking juices to avoid an oily gravy. Place the cooking travy on the hob over a medium / high heat. If you need to deglaze the cooking tray to get all the bits off the bottom heat up the tray and then pour in some stock / wine / water but just enough to do the deglazing. Add some flour to the cooking juices (this is a Welsh method so it does make a thick gravy). Stir the flour into the the juices and keep cooking it until the flour is cooked. It will go a slightly darked colour as it cooks, but keep stiring to avoid anything burning. Then pour in you liquid (stock / wine / water)a bit at a time to make sure you don't get too many lumps. Keep stiring over the heat whilst piuring in the liquid. It's ready to serve when you have the right thickness for you.

Comment: I'm a big fan of lining the bottom of the pan with onions.  Not only does it add flavour, it allows me to roast poultry upside down without having the skin stick to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Skim off the fat, make a roux with it. Whisk in the rest of the pan juices (i forgot, yes, deglaze), add beef/chicken stock to bring it up to your desired texture.