# Grilled Turkey and Gravy

Tags: grilling, turkey, gravy

I'd like to grill my turkey this Thanksgiving. Cook's Illustrated's method has you put the turkey on a V-Rack on the grill.  If I do this I won't have any pan drippings for my gravy.

Is there an advantage to putting the turkey right on the grill?  Can I just put my roasting pan + turkey right on the grill?

Answer (score 4):

I grilled my turkey this year, here is how I made the gravy:

- Cut the wing tips off
- Make a mirepoix (chopped carrots, celery and onions)
- Brown the mirepoix really well.
- Brown the neck, wing tips and giblets (but not the liver-fry that separately and eat it for a snack)
- Simmer the mirepoix and browned meat bits in a few cups of water for an hour or more to make a rich stock.
- Add browned mushrooms if you like (adds umami).

  This can all be done while the turkey is being grilled.

  When you take the turkey off, put it on a platter to stand.  You will collect some juices in the tray.  Use these juices and the stock you made to make the gravy.

See: [Making a natural gravy?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2353/making-a-natural-gravy)

Comment: Canadians: the brave advance scouts of Thanksgiving.

Comment: Just trying to help out our Southern Brethren.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen the method in question, but assuming you're cooking the turkey with indirect heat all you're really doing is roasting it on the grill. Given that, there's no reason you can't put your bird in a pan to catch the drippings the same way you would in an oven, provided it all fits in the grill, of course.